# One author citation in LaTeX

Tags: biblatex, citing, author

I use LaTeX in Overleaf where I write my thesis. 
For bibliography I use this:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt, dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

In order to insert a reference in my text, I use

```
\parencite{}
```

However, I want only the first author to be visible in the citation in the text, not the rest of the authors like in the following image for example.
How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the option `maxnames` and the related options from the manual:

> maxnames= default: 3
>
> A threshold affecting all lists of names ( author , editor , etc.). If a list exceeds this threshold, i.e., if it holds more than  names, it is automatically truncated according to the setting of the `minnames` option. `maxnames` is the master option which sets `maxbibnames`, `maxcitenames` and `maxsortnames` . Note that the `uniquelist` feature can locally override `maxnames` , see the documentation of the `uniquelist` option in § 3.1.2.3 and § 4.11.4.

The following should do:

```
\usepackage[
    style=authoryear,
    sorting=nyt,
    dashed=false,
    maxnames=1,
]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used this: `\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt,dashed=false,uniquelist=false,maxnames=1]{biblatex}`  and in my text I have only the first author cited. However, that happens in the bibliography too and I want all the authors referred there.

Comment: Then you may use the `maxcitenames` option only instead of `maxnames`.